# Power BI NativeQuery - cannot convert from Type to Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I created SQL stored procedure with 2 parameters: **DateFrom** and **DateTo** (both are of type DATE in my sql procedure).

I want to write a native query in Power Query Editor so first I created there 2 parameters for dates (type:date/time) : **StartDate** and **EndDate**. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to write a native query, the following error occurs: "can't convert from data type Record to Text". Do you know what's wrong with it?

This is procedure invoke:

[image]

and my M code:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("Server\12", "Base1"),

        Query = Value.NativeQuery(
            Source, 
            [Query="EXEC [dbo].[sp_Sales] @DateFrom = '" & Date.ToText(StartDate) & "', @DateTo = '" & Date.ToText(EndDate) & "'"])
  
in 
 Query
```

I also tried with more " :

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("Server\12", "Base1"),

        Query = Value.NativeQuery(
            Source, 
            [Query="EXEC [dbo].[sp_Sales] @DateFrom = """ & Date.ToText(StartDate) & """, @DateTo = """ & Date.ToText(EndDate) & """"])
  
in 
 Query
```

where is the problem?

Comment: You can first try with a stored procedure without parameter so that you become sure your communication between server and power bi is ok. After that try with passing parameters. Here I would suggest to take parameter value as text and then convert them to DateTime at the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I removed parameters from procedure and tried with NativeQuery but it failed. I also turned off native query permission in Settings. Same error comes up again, what went wrong?

Comment: ook I did it! Finally! I've spent a few weeks on it, nobody knew how to do it:) Now I can pass parameters from visualization right into SQL stored procedure and refresh all data:) I'm so happy with that!

Comment: Hi @Muska, nice to see your issue resolved. You can post your own answer here, so that other people also learn and know about the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for it. The key is to use NativeQuery here. The steps are as following:

1. Create stored procedure with parameters (e.g. **DateFrom** and **DateTo**) and import data to Power BI
2. In PowerQuery Editor create 2 parameters. Let's say **startDate** and **endDate**. Set some default values:

[image]

3. Go to 'Advance Editor' to change M code. The proper one should be as following:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("ServerName\12", "Base2"),
    Query = Value.NativeQuery(
            Source, 
            "EXEC [dbo].[storedProcedure_XYZ] @DateFrom = '" & Date.ToText(startDate) & "', @DateTo = '" & Date.ToText(endDate) & "'")
    
in
    
Query
```

**@DateFrom** and **@DateTo** are SQL parameters, PQ parameters (startDate and endDate) must be assigned to them in a way I showed above.

Important thing is that you can't put EXEC.... statement in 'SQL statement field' for importing data (of course you need to fill out server name etc.).
I mean you can do it first to import raw data (see 1st point) but after that this field should remain empty. The whole job is now done by your M code using Native Query.

[image]

4. After clicking 'Ok' in your 'Advanced Editor' (see 3rd point) your SQL query will be executed along with parameters. Now you can see data refreshed in Power BI.
5. Go to visualization layer in your Power BI. Click on this little arrow down for 'Transform Data' and choose 'Edit Parameters':

[image]

6. Now enter values for your parameters.

[image]

Click OK and that's it! Your SQL query is being refreshed now based on parameters you passed from PBI Visualization layer and all refreshed data will be loaded into your data model in PBI - that means your visualizations will be updated automatically with new data. It's not statis any longer - it's dynamic now:)

Another good thing about it is that your base table which you imported to PQ from SQL  won't change to function (as it usually is when you parametrize queries) - it still remain table even though you use parameters on your base query. It makes less problems with loading data into PBI data model, all columns remain on their place and none of them are removed. It works perfectly for me.

I also turned off Native Query Approval (go to Options>Security) as to PBI doesn't ask you for permission to execute your query. That's good thing to do when you use Native Query (bear in mind security issues, it's important here).

[image]